# How do I connect apache with wordpress in docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, apache

I've created a docker yml file what contains the db and wordpress image and I want to connect Apache to Wordpress. How do I let Apache know the PHP files from Wordpress and how do I can connect to my webserver with my own url.

These are my docker containers which are running
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wi1F.png

Is this way right?

I edit this cfg "wp-config.php" for my example url:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.example.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.example.com/'); `
```

But I can't connect it.

Comment: I think it's because your httpd container has not opened port. You have to run it with `-p 80:80` or whatever port you want on the left side. But I would suggest to pull official wordpress image with apache inside. For example `wordpress:php7.4-apache`. You don't have to run httpd as a standalone container. If it's not your problem, pls share your docker-compose yml file for better understanding.

Comment: its the standart docker-compose for wordpress. i post it.

Comment: Ok so you don't have to run apache as a standalone container. Wordpress with the latest tag has already apache installed inside. With this docker-compose.yml file up you already have running apache server on the url localhost:8080. Switch localhost for you local docker setup (maybe 127.0.0.1:8080).

Comment: if apache is already installed in wordpress with the latest tag. do im ready to start this yml file for my webserver then?

Comment: Yes, if you are in the cloud or anywhere you want, than start this docker-compose.yml and you are ready to go on the <webserverIPaddress>:8080. If you want to get it right, you can run it on default port 80 not 8080, update your DNS A record to point to your IP address and update your wp-config file.

Comment: this thing aside, why would you connect wordpress on apache to docker? I mean what is your demanding use case to do so ? (ie) implement this technical stack. Just asking

Answer (score 0):

@czende

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8080:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
db_data: {}
```